# How can I use the NOW function to determine if the current time is between two different times?

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

[image]As the title says, I have the current time in cell `L9` using function `NOW()` and would like cell `G9` to display either `YES` or `NO` depending on if cell `L9` time falls between two times displayed in cells `L19` and `M19`

I currently have the formula `=IF(AND(L9>=L$19,L9<=M$19),"YES","NO")` in cell `G9` But i am getting a `NO` response and cant figure out why

Comment: Try `=IF(AND(A1>=(TODAY()+A3),A1<=(TODAY()+A4)),"Yes","No")`.

Comment: Sample data added.

Comment: `NOW` returns the current *date* and time.

Comment: So it cannot be done? Is there an alternate that only returns time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOW` returns the current *date* and time. "Remove" the date portion of `NOW` by using `INT`. In `L9`, use:

```
NOW()-INT(NOW())
```